# nginx + docker: http to https redirection

Tags: docker, nginx, https

I have an nginx inside a docker container which I want to force SSL on all request. Because I need to expose the webserver port in a different port outside the container, I'm not using standar ports when accesing the server.

I mapped the SSL port 443 inside my container to 8888 outside, so when I write the URL https://myserver:8888 the HTTPS works fine.

What happens when I don't use the https prefix? The port 443 is still listening but since I'm not using https schema I get the following error:

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

If I redirect request to port 80 to 443 it is not enough, since because I'm accesign by the port 8888 the all requests are incoming by port 443, but I can not guarantee the schema used is HTTP.

I mean, the following block has not effect because I'm not exposing port 80 outside, only 8888 which maps direcly to 443

```
server {
        server_name myserver;
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;
}
```

How can I force it to work even when the user puts http on the URL?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have to use two different ports : for example 8888 and 8889.

Bind the first port to the container's 80, and the second to 443.

If a client want to contact your container on http it will have to use 8888 (-> 80). If the vhost is well configured nginx will serve a 301 or 302 HTTP return code (a redirect) to the https port (8889 -> 443).

So your return might look like

```
  return 301 https://$host:8889$request_uri;
```

And the client will start a TLS connection on the right port.

---

Due to technical limitation it's pretty hard to use the same port for both clear traffic and TLS-encrypted one, so most of the webservers will listen on two distinct ports : 80 for plain-text and 443 for TLS.

Comment: Thank you, I though about thiss aproach, but I discarded it since I don't wont the internal container configuration depend on external exposed ports (which can be changed on the future). In fact, it doesn't make sense for me to export http on a different port to end up redirecting to the https port, I only wanted everything work  without the need to write "https" in the URL. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: In this case you can enable redirect at your CDN level (Cloudlfare for example). If you're on Kubernetes you can do the TLS termination with ingresses, and if you're on a single server you may want to use https://traefik.io/